# Is there a way to batch export Illustrator symbols as pngs?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols

I use Illustrator as my main graphics program for building modular UI components.

[image]

Context: I'm exploring an animation software, [Pixate](http://pixate.com), and will need to upload all UI assets to the project library — is there any way to make this any easier by somehow batch exporting all the symbols in a Symbol Library?

I have not yet been able to find a solution online that solves this, and would appreciate any direction!

Comment: Hi Ksy, have you checked out this thread already? [Export Symbol as PNG](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/837709)

Comment: Wow, I must be bad at googling things :/ Perfect -- thank you! I will try this scripting solution out

Comment: This seems to be a great solution for elements of same size (e.g., icons) -- also appears to require dragging and dropping all symbols onto an artboard and making a grid -- I think I'll wing it this time, but I'll be using Photoshop next time to make this process easier and slice the UI components :)

Comment: Although this is not a way to batch export, I feel that the solution from [this thread](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/17381/14984) in using **Command-Option-Shift-3 (Mac)** saves me the most manual tasks

Comment: If you did have all objects pasted into the document wouldn't the answer from Jonathan be faster?

Comment: It's a pretty dense AI file, with multiple layers within layers -- ultimately, this came down what would work best with my current workflow preference. This may not be relevant to the question posted, but I've decided to use Keynote (instead of Pixate) to prototype. This way, I can copy and paste objects with ease. There's a [great link here](https://vimeo.com/100377108)

Answer (score 3):

The following script will export all your symbols from the symbol library and save them to a chosen folder.

You just have to make sure all your layers are hidden first.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var symbolCount = doc.symbols.length;

if (symbolCount >= 1) {

    if (confirm("Are all your layers hidden?")) {

        // create temp layer
        doc.layers.add();

        // create directory
        var dest = Folder.selectDialog();
        dest.create();

        // loop through symbols
        for (var i = 0; i < doc.symbols.length; i++) {

            // place a symbol instance - temp
            var s = doc.symbolItems.add(doc.symbols[i]);         

            // assign name
            var filename = (doc.symbols[i].name)

            // export symbols
            savePNG(dest, filename);

            // delete temp symbol instance
            s.remove();
        }
        // remove temp layer
        doc.layers[0].remove();
    }

    function savePNG(dest, filename) {
        // save options
        var type = ExportType.PNG24;
        var options = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
        options.transparency = true;

        // file
        var file = new File(dest + "/" + filename);

        // export
        doc.exportFile(file, type, options);
    }

} else {
    alert("You don't have any symbols in this document");
}
```

You can find this script at: https://gist.github.com/shaneparsons/1717f21a757f24fb4559